# Force the use of a xmlns prefix in soap message

Tags: xml, wcf, cxf

I need to force WCF to use an XML namespace prefix when calling a java SOAP service

My outgoing soap message currently looks like this:

```
<s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<getStuff xmlns="http://XXXXXX.com/">
<Id>84</Id>
</getStuff>
</s:Body>
```

I need it to utilize a namespace prefix for the cxf service to correctly parse the message.

```
<s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<nsXX:getStuff xmlns:nsXX="http://XXXXXX.com/">
<nsXX:Id>84</nsXX:Id>
</nsXX:getStuff>
</s:Body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before I go on to one solution, notice that the two XMLs are different: in the first, the element `<Id>` is on the `http://XXXXXX.com/` namespace, while on the second it's on the empty namespace. Is that really what you want?

If so, you'll need to use a custom encoder to be able to change the prefix used by WCF when writing the message. One easy implementation would be to wrap the existing encoder and delegate most calls to the original one. When writing the outgoing message, you'd first delegate it to the original encoder, writing it to a local buffer. Then you can change the XML as you wish, and later return that message to the caller.

The post at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2010/06/13/changing-prefixes-in-xml-responses.aspx shows one implementation for this scenario.

Comment: I editing the original to reflect the namespaces as you stated.  Thanks for the link, indeed your implementation and andrew-arnott 's XmlObjectSerializer was what solved the problem.